# Given an array of integers and target, return true if any two elements sum to target

Tags: ruby

As the title states, I'm looking to find two elements whose sum is equal to the target integer. I've already worked out the solution below, but this works only for unique integers. I'm having an issue when it comes to duplicate values. Of course, I can use multiple loops that keep track of two separate indices and, in this way, make sure those two indices are the same. However, I wanted to see if there was a way to solve this with one iteration.

```
two_sum([1,2,3,4,5,6], 8) = true
two_sum([4,4], 8) = false

def two_sum(array, target)
  idx = 0 
  while idx < array.length 
    complement = target - array[idx]
    if array.include?(complement) && complement != array[idx]
      return true 
    end 
    idx+=1 
  end 
  return false 
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'set'

def two_sum(arr, tot)
  st = Set.new
  arr.each { |n| st.include?(tot-n) ? (return true) : st << n } 
  false
end

two_sum [1,2,3,4,5,6], 8    #=> true 
two_sum [4,4], 8            #=> true 
two_sum [1,2,3,4,5,6], 3421 #=> false
```

If you'd prefer to return the two values that sum to `tot` (when `true`), replace `true` with `[n, tot-n]` (or just return `n`, the other being `tot - n`).

I used a set rather than an array for faster lookups.

Comment: And it's O(n) vs O(n**2).  Nice!

Answer (score 0):

```
def two_sum(array, target)
  array.combination(2).each { |pair| return true if pair.inject(:+) == target }
  return false;
end
```

Comment: `array.combination(2).any? { |a,b| a+b == target }`

Comment: I suggest `array.combination(2).find { |a,b|  a+b == target }`, which returns either the desired pair or `nil`. Edit: Egad! @steenslag posted almost exactly the same comment less than a minute before I did, even the same block variables!  I do think `find` is preferred to `any?` as the desired pair is wanted.

Comment: @CarySwoveland from the header: "... return true if any two elements sum to target".