# find out whether there are two numbers sum is 0 in array

Tags: algorithm, dynamic

say there's an array [1, 2, 9, 4, -5, -4], we need to find out whether there are 2 numbers that sum to 0. Time complexity should be O(n), and only constant additional space should be used. It is allowed to modify the original array.

I got this as an interview question but didn't figure out how to solve it.  thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given an array of integers and target, return true if any two elements sum to target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40770188/given-an-array-of-integers-and-target-return-true-if-any-two-elements-sum-to-ta)

Comment: Hey Prune, I don't think those answers meet O(n) time complexity and constant space complexity.

Comment: I feel like there's a bit-manipulation solution to this.

Comment: Read again: the answer with two votes is **O(N)**

Comment: Read again - this question is asking for additional constant space, while that one uses set

Comment: Hi @0x499602D2, thanks, that's what I thought of, but I'm not familiar with it, could you let me know more what you think? Thanks

Comment: I'm no more familiar with it than you, but when I see a problem like this with interesting constraints I figure some bitwise magic will have to be used. But I wouldn't know where to start.

Comment: I think this problem is missing some constraints, O(n) time and O(n) space complexity is easy; O(n log n) time and O(1) space is doable; but I don't think O(n) time, O(1) space is feasible without additional constraints.

Comment: if numbers are less than 32, one may stock the number of value ```i``` into ```int positiveSet``` or ```int negativeSet``` at the ```ith``` bit, then at the end take the binary-and ```&``` between ```positiveSet``` and ```negativeSet``` and check its (non)nullity. (0 not handled). This feels really cheap though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we know the range of the numbers of the array, we can create a hash map that would consume a constant additional space to solve the  problem in O(n) time complexity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int arr[]={1, 2, 9, 4, -5, -4};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    const int N=1000001; // the maximum non negative value for arr[i] is 1,000,000
    int hashmap [N];

    bool found=false;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){ //initialize the hashmap
        hashmap[i]=0;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int temp = abs( arr[i] );
        if (  hashmap[ temp ] == 0  ){ // no collision 
            if (arr[i] >= 0){
                hashmap[ temp ] = 1;   //mark the hashmap 1 for positive arr[i]
            }else{
                hashmap[ temp ] = -1;  //mark the hashmap -1 for negative arr[i]
            }
        }else{                         //collision
            if (hashmap[ temp ] == 1 && arr[i] <= 0){
                found = true;
                break;
            }else if (hashmap[ temp ] == -1 && arr[i] > 0){
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if (found){
        cout << "Found" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**General comment:**
If we can modify the original array and there is no limit to the size of the values in the array, you can store as much information in each element of the array.
see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel_numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering)

---

In this special case you can do it even simpler.

We only need to know if a value and its negative are both existing in the array that can be accomplished like this:

`a :=` the biggest number in the array.
`b :=` the smallest negative number in the array.

`bits := 2 * max(a,-b)`

Let `m` be an integer-variable with `bits` bits. (all initialized with 0)

```
// Now we read the array (time **O(n)**).
for(i=0; n>i; i++){
  if(0<=a[n]){ 
    if(m.testBit(2*a[n] + 1))
      return true;  // negative value was already there
    m.setBit(2*a[n]);
  }
  else{ 
    if(m.testBit(2*a[-n]))
      return true;  // positive value was already there
    m.setBit(2*(-n) + 1);
}
return false;
```

If we use the first array-element to store `m` (we do not need the original value anymore after setting m the first time) it kind of takes no extra space.

But this is kind of cheating because we need the array element to have enough bits.

But we only used O(n) time and no extra space at all.